# Intercepting POST in sails

Tags: rest, sails.js

In my sails application, I have a guest model which contains information about a registered guest. I have been tasked with creating some analytical graphs for a client-side UI and as the needed database size has grown, I can no longer get all guests and analyze on the client side.

This leads me to my question, I was thinking that the best way to track these statistics would be to have running totals in the guest controller and return those and modifying the totals whenever a Guest is created or deleted. Is it possible to intercept POST and DELETES to a model, perhaps in a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Sails.js documentation for blueprint actions](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?blueprint-actions):

> Blueprint actions (not to be confused with blueprint action routes) are generic actions designed to work with any of your controllers that have a model of the same name (e.g. ParrotController would need a Parrot model). Think of them as the default behavior for your application. For instance, if you have a User.js model and an empty UserController.js controller, find, create, update, destroy, populate, add and remove actions exist implicitly, without you having to write them.
>
> By default, the blueprint RESTful routes and shortcut routes are bound to their corresponding blueprint actions. However, any blueprint action can be overridden for a particular controller by creating a custom action in that controller file (e.g. ParrotController.find). Alternatively, you can override the blueprint action everywhere in your app by creating your own custom blueprint action. (e.g. api/blueprints/create.js).
>
> The current version of Sails ships with the following blueprint actions:
>
> - find
> - findOne
> - create
> - update
> - destroy
> - populate
> - add
> - remove

So if you want to "intercept" requests to create or destroy a `User` model, simply create a `create` or `destroy` method in the `UserController.js` file.